InkScape commandline interface to remove icc-color while converting
I'm trying to convert some .ai files to .svg and the resulting SVGs only work in Inkscape itself. Not on GIMP or web browsers (they display a blank SVG)
Seems like the problem is that they don't support icc-color in the stroke attribute.
How can I tell Inkscape to ignore this value?
Example of one of the paths:
<path
   d="M 0,0 C -0.811,1.082 -2.816,-0.186 -3.541,-0.653"
   style="stroke:#000000 icc-color(sRGB-IEC61966-2, 0.1, 0, 0, 0);" />

At the moment I used sed to separate icc-color from the rest of the stroke, but I'd like to have a less hacky way.
sed -i -e 's/icc-color/;icc-color/g' filename.svg


Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Looks to me like the problem here is the SVG path element is just off the page/viewbox (top left corner). That's why it's not showing up, and has nothing to do with the icc-colour profile. If you adjust the page to fit the element, then it will work in GIMP and browsers.  I just tested it. I've no idea how to do this from the command line, but in Inkscape it's simple enough. Select all, and Edit > Resize page to selection.

I removed unnecessary parts in the example I showed. All paths have transform attribute and it brings them into the view. And I'm sure about icc-color issue, because when I put a ; before it to make a "valid" stroke, everything shows on the screen.

Share the problematic SVG here: https://svgshare.com/ - I can take a look. No promises though.

https://svgshare.com/s/15ZA, to make it show in browsers, add ; after each stroke:#000000 which turns it into: https://svgshare.com/s/15_R

I had a look and here's what I found.  It's an absolute mess. It has thousands of useless clipping masks. I'm not surprised a browser can't display this. I tried to fix it for you.  Ungrouped everything. Selected all. Released all the clipping masks, which took so long I though Inkscape had crashed. Selected and deleted all the pointless clipping masks. Selected all, and changed the strokes to a normal RGB colour. Merged the styles to CSS to save repetition. Copied and pasted all to a new doc. Grouped each graphic. Here's the result

As to how it got in such a mess, clearly it wasn't originally created in Inkscape.  Do you happen to know what software was used to create it?  After the cleanup I did, the file size has been reduced by about half, from 925kb down to 450kb.

Oh wow! You didn't have to fix it! Thanks. I'm working on a design app that already supports SVG for import, I'm trying to add DWG and AI too. These AI files as far as I know are from AutoCad, and I converted them to SVG via Inkscape commandline. (And I had no luck converting DWG to SVG yet)

That explains the weird construction: no closed paths, thousands of separate paths, and the clipping path mess. If you can, it's probably best to avoid CAD software or formats for vector graphics that are intended for the web (ie SVG).  I know some often have ways to export as SVG, but they're not really designed for vector graphics.  AI files are generally an Adobe Illustrator format, but that's not to say that they haven't been converted from something else originally.  You might have more success using another intermediate format, such as PDF.  Illustrator and Inkscape can both open PDFs.
